# How to deploy Parse Server with Express, Nginx and pm2

Tags: express, parse-platform, pm2

I have successfully deployed the parse-server with pm2, MongoDB and Nginx and I can POST and GET from it from outside the localhost. I am doing this on DigitalOcean and I used this [page](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-a-parse-app-to-parse-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) as a reference. I now want to add ExpressJS to the npm global install of parse and I don't know how to do this. I got the Parse+ExpressJS to work by manually using "npm start" as per the Parse tutorial [parse-server-example](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server-example). How do I include it for the global install so that it is included when pm2 starts parse?

Here is my ecosystem.json, if that is useful.

```js
{                                      
    "apps" : [{
      "name"        : "parse-wrapper",
      "script"      : "/usr/local/bin/parse-server",
      "watch"       : true,
      "merge_logs"  : true,               
      "cwd"         : "/home/parse",       
      "env": {                             
        "PARSE_SERVER_CLOUD_CODE_MAIN": "/home/parse/cloud/main.js",
        "PARSE_SERVER_DATABASE_URI": "mongodb://<user>:<password>@127.0.0.1:27017/dev",                        
        "PARSE_SERVER_APPLICATION_ID": "<myAppId>",
        "PARSE_SERVER_MASTER_KEY": "myMasterKey",
      }                                 
    }]                                   
}
```

The pm2 command sequence that I used is:

```
pm2 start ecosystem.json
pm2 save
sudo pm2 startup ubuntu -u parse --hp /home/parse/
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your ref repo express is already installed with Parse using package.json
you can use express methods in [index.js](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server-example/blob/master/index.js)

No need to install express as a global as it's already mentioned in [package.json](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server-example/blob/master/package.json) file

To start using pm2 you can mention script argument as below

```
script: "npm run start"
```

Move ecosystem.json in your project root folder and run pm2 start command in your project folder.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So to be clear, I download the parse-server-example repo, and execute the following commands:

`    cd <parse-server-example-dir>;
    pm2 npm run start;
    pm2 save;
    sudo pm2 startup ubuntu -u parse --hp /home/parse/<parse-server-example-dir>`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out and this is the sequence of commands that I used to configure pm2.

```
<login as the parse user, or su -l parse>
git clone https://github.com/ppk007/parse-server-example ~/git/parse-server-dev
cd ~/get/parse-server-dev
npm install
<change the config files - I edited index.js>
pm2 start index.js
pm2 save
exit # exit the parse user shell and go to the normal user shell
sudo pm2 startup ubuntu -u parse --hp /home/parse/
```